# Is "to have a perfect ear for music" a metaphor or a metonymy?

Tags: metaphors, metonyms

This phrase seems to be a metaphor to me, however I guess you could say "ear" might be referring to a concept of being able to make music well. Would you say it's a metaphor or metonymy?

Comment: What phrase? There's no phrase in the body of the question.

Comment: The idiom is *an ear for* something, not necessarily perfect. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+an+ear+for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *have a good ear for music* has nothing to do with making music: it means to be able to listen to music, put it in its technical and historical context, and understand what is going on in it. “Ear” thus stands for the great complex of physical, intellectual and emotional capabilities which constitute the critical sense.

This figure, in which a part stands for the whole, is termed [*synecdoche*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche). Some people regard synecdoche as a kind of *metonymy*; others specifically exclude synecdoche from metonymy, insisting that a figure is only properly termed metonymy if the term alluded to does not embrace the alluding term.

Comment: In other words, you can get away with using "metaphor", "metonymy", **or** "synecdoche" to refer to _a good ear for music_, and nobody can gainsay you, because there is no ISO standard for metaphor. Thank gods.