# As far as the eye (eyes) can/could see

Tags: grammar

I know "as far as the eye can/could see" is an idiom, which means "for a long distance until something is so far away and small it cannot be seen any more", but why is it "eye" instead of "eyes"? Thank you!

Comment: "Beauty is in **the eye** of the beholder" The expression "the (human) eye" represents the noun *eyesight*. Similarly, "We walked there **on foot**" uses the singular instead of the plural form, the expression "on foot" is short for  *using our feet to get there*.

Comment: Related: [Is it "look in the eye" or "look in the eyes"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/447027/is-it-look-in-the-eye-or-look-in-the-eyes) and [Why does “something catch my eye” but not “both my eyes”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267910/why-does-something-catch-my-eye-but-not-both-my-eyes)

Comment: Also [compare 'in the eye of' vs 'in the eyes of'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/533231/compare-in-the-eye-of-vs-in-the-eyes-of) and [Is "to have a perfect ear for music" a metaphor or a metonymy?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143019/is-to-have-a-perfect-ear-for-music-a-metaphor-or-a-metonymy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same sort of generalised usage as in "the pen is mightier than the sword", and it does not refer to any specific eye. A pair of eyes can see no further than a single eye can, so it is not necessary to suggest there is need for more than one eye.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses! Now I understand why 